# AngularJS directive: Check if attribute is assignable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to implement an AngularJS directive that takes attribute-flag `selected`, which indicates initial state + any current value, if it is assignable.

How can I implement a verification in AngularJS directive to see that the attribute is assignable, before setting a value in it?

```
app.directive('customControl', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            selected: '=?', // optional, initial + current selected state;
        },
        templateUrl: 'views/directives/customControl.html',
        link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
            if (/* scope.selected is assignable */) {
                scope.selected = /* some value */;
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `$parse` service for that:

```
link: function(scope){
    var selectedGet = $parse(attrs.selected);
    var selectedSet = selectedGet.assign;

    // etc...

    if (selectedSet){
      selectedSet(scope.$parent, obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried using `try/catch`, it didn't work, the exception still propagates outside the catch block.

Comment: @vitaly-t, yeah, you're right - it wouldn't catch it... I'll remove it

Comment: Why use `selectedSet(scope, obj)` instead of `scope.selected = value`? I have tried the latter first, and it worked.

Comment: @vitaly-t, either way would work in your case, but the former approach works even if you didn't have an isolate scope. Actually, it should be `scope.$parent`